# Marvelous Designer API

Tags: python-imaging-library

I´m trying to use Marvelous Designer API through Python with Jupiter Notebook. I have an error when I tried to run this command:

*from PythonQt import Marvelous Designer API*

The error is:

*No module PythonQt found*

This module is installed, I have confirmed this in the environment of Anaconda.

Do you know what is the problem??

Thank you!